# Visual Basic - Directory.Move(sourceDir, "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks") Not properly moving folder

Tags: vb.net, directory, windows-task-scheduler

A program I am developing is using a Windows Tasks Scheduler script inside a project folder (CRM_Window10). I am trying to have it so that when my program runs it moves the folder with the script to `"C:\Windows\System32\Tasks"` where it then creates the folder win10 and puts the contents of CRM_Window10 into. To accomplish this I am using the `IO.Directory.Move` method. I am not getting an error and I know it is moving the folder because it deletes CRM_Window10, but it does not appear inside of the `"C:\Windows\System32\Tasks"` folder.

```
IO.Directory.Move(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\idle_setup\CRM_Window10", "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\win10")
```

The expected result that it moves the contents of CRM_Window10 to a newly created folder win10 in the `"C:\Windows\System32\Tasks"` folder with the script inside. The actual results are that it tries to move CRM_Window10 but can't make it inside of the "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks" folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, considering no application should be messing with the system32 folder, you've got yourself here a classic X/Y problem. You're asking how to do X, but you really need to do Y. You should [edit] and let us know what you're attempting to do by moving folders around. Or, just run your application as admin and move on.

Comment: Your program probably does not have permissions to modify thinigs in System32. This is generally for a good reason.